# App didn't connect to the Host?

Tags: android

I was trying to connect my app with a host, i get all the codes as well but it didn't connect 
Giving me That message in the logcat verbose when i click on the [Menu](https://imageshack.com/i/pcREVybUp) button in the emulator and this message when i click on the [Refresh](https://imageshack.com/i/pc4mkNsVp) button

Here is MainActivity.java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment()
                        .Commit());
             }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public ForecastFragment Commit() {
        return null;
    }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            String forecastJsonStr = null;
    }
```

Here is ForecastFragment.java class:

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment
{
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    public ForecastFragment()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    public void onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }


    public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh)
        {
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("94043");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] data =
        {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - foggy - 70/46",
                "weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Rainy - 64/51",
                "Fri - Foggy - 70/46",
                "Sat - Sunny - 76/68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(data));


         mForecastAdapter =

                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                        weekForecast);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public ForecastFragment Commit() {
        return null;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>
    {
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();


        private String getReadableDateString(long time)
        {
            Date date = new Date(time * 1000);
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
            return format.format(date).toString();
        }


        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {

            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for (int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);


                long dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);


                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }

            for (String s : resultStrs) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
            }
            return resultStrs;

        }


        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            if (params.length == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String format = "json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;


            try
            {
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_param = "MODE";
                final String UNITS_param = "UNITS";
                final String DAYS_param = "CNT";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_param, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_param, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_param, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built Uri " + builtUri.toString());


                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON String: " + forecastJsonStr);

                }
                catch (IOException e)
               {
                 Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
                   return null;
               }
                    finally
            {
                    if (urlConnection != null)
                    {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                    catch (final IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            try
            {
                return  getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                    return null;
        }

            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result)
            {
                if (result != null)
                {

                    mForecastAdapter.clear();
                    for (String dayForecastStr : result)
                    {
                        mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Now i get over all the errors and recorrect the code in ForecastFragment.java class, so why it didn't connect to the host giving me the same error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `doInBackground()` is empty:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    return null;
}
```

There's a typo in the other `doInBackGround()` method name (should have lowercase `g`). Remove the empty method and rename the other with code in it so it can be run by `AsyncTask`.

Comment: what should i do for that error "https://imageshack.com/i/exYvQ3HMp"
and i missing a return statement down there :/

Comment: Post it as a text in your question.

Comment: i modified all the code in ForecastFragment.java class but it didn't connect to the Host, i still Receives that message in the verbose logcat, what should i do !!